# Does NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L) improve not only computation time but precision of the fft?

Tags: matlab, fft

Basically my title contains everything: does the use of 2^nextpow2(L) when estimating a computationally efficient N-points for the computation of FFT also influence the precision of the coefficients? For instance, to compare the output of xcorr with that of the FFT (by the Wiener-Khinchin theorem). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This second parameter is equivalent to padding the input with zeros. This does two things:

1. It changes your signal. The DFT assumes the signal is periodic. By padding with zeros you change the shape of this periodic signal.
2. It changes the location of the samples in the frequency domain. The frequencies that are computed depend on the length of the signal, you change this length, you change the transform's frequency axis.

Whether either of these influence your later computations depends on what those computations are.

Comment: Thanks, Cris. However, if the second parameter equals the length of the signal, then there is no padding. I asked in the first place, because I noticed that when computing the fft without parameter (= n of samples in the signal) and computing it using 2nextpow2(), only in the latter case the values of the IFFT(FFT(x)) were identical to computing the xcorr of the signal x.

Comment: Of course, the second parameter pads to that length, so if your signal is already that length, no padding happens. Note that, `ifft(fft(x))==x`. The cross correlation is `ifft(abs(fft(x)).^2)`. I don't think the cross correlation is affected by the padding.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I forgot to include the absolute value (or else multiply by the complex conjugate). I checked that cross correlation is affected by the padding. The higher the N in fft, the more precise. Would appreciate if you could check since Im new in Matlab.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein: the larger the padding, the more values you get in the xcorr signal. But I don't think that necessarily translates to higher precision. It would be interesting to see if you can obtain the same result by interpolating into the xcorr signal obtained without interpolation.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try that. THanks!